# Dig connection timed out while Ping and nslookup work fine

Tags: kali-linux, dns, dig, nslookup

Whenever I run the command dig, the connection times out and no servers are reached.Specifying the DNS server to query makes no difference.

[image]

Nslookup and Ping on the other hand seem to be working just fine and return the answers.

[image]

In the packets captured by Wireshark there are 3 DNS queries but none of them gets a response.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397). Copy and paste the text itself

Comment: Is `dig` aliased to something else? You can override the alias using `\dig google.com`. Also, can you paste the output of `\dig google.com +trace`?

Comment: Thank you for answering but unfortunately, that's not it. The response for trace is the same.

Comment: Yes. To the same result. I have mentioned above that "specifying the DNS server makes no difference" in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try `dig +search google.com`.

The default behavior of `dig` is not to use the resolver search-option.

From the `dig` manual page:

> +[no]search
>
> Use [do not use] the search list defined by the searchlist or
> domain directive in resolv.conf (if any). The search list is not
> used by default.